# Postgres Regex to Return first word before comma and first word after

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to get the first and last name from a column using regex but I'm stumped.

I'm trying:

```
select
    substring('SMIRTH JR, DAVID ALLEN', '^[^ ,]+') as namemodified
```

it should return

```
SMIRTH, DAVID
```

but it only returns the last name. I can't figure out how to get both.

I also need it to work for:

```
SMIRTHJR, DAVID ALLEN
```

since the data isn't very clean. Any ideas?

Comment: The Expected output is 'SMIRTH, DAVID' --oops I'll edit my question.

Comment: I tested it, but I get 'SMIRTHJR, DAVID ALLEN' not 'SMIRTH, DAVID'

Comment: Try `select regexp_replace('SMIRTH, DAVID ALLEN', '^([^,\s]+?)([JS]R)?\y[^,]*,\s*(\S+\y).*$', '\3, \1')`

Comment: It doesn't filter the name at all still

Comment: Ok, maybe [like here](http://rextester.com/OTHS13697).

Comment: I see - your solution does work for Postgres 9.x I'm at work stuck on 5.1.1 and it won't work there. I'll still vote your answer though if you want to post it.

Comment: I wonder what is supported in PostgreSQL 5.1.1. Is `\y` word boundary supported? Try [this](http://rextester.com/GDRM53210).

Comment: I'm getting nulls for both sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp_matches` function instead of `substring` (assuming *Postgresql* 9.x):

```
select
    regexp_matches(regexp_replace('SMIRTHJR, DAVID ALLEN','(JR|SR),', ','), 
                   '([^\s,]+).*?(, [^\s,]+) [^\s,]+$') as namemodified
```

---

The above will return `SMIRTH, DAVID` for both input strings `SMIRTHJR, DAVID ALLEN` or `SMIRTH JR, DAVID ALLEN`

Comment: `^[^\s,]+|[^\s,]+$` only returns `SMIRTH`.

Comment: But for *I also need it to work for: `SMIRTHJR, DAVID ALLEN` since the data isn't very clean.* requirement, it would have been even easier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, while *since the data isn't very clean* - someone can invent additional cases like `SMIRTHJR,DAVIDALLEN` - what now?

Comment: The data always has a space after the comma so we just have to worry about the JR/SR and spaces. I just wish there was a solution that worked on 5.1.1 - I'm stuck on that old version. :(

Comment: Using @WiktorStribiżew 's tool it works, but on my version I get an error saying that it doesn't recognize the function  - regexp_matches isn't supported in my version :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, while it works now, the main is issue is his old version, anyway

Comment: @excelVBAmaster.com, concluding this story the good advise for you would be specifying postgresql version in your further questions

Comment: I will give you both credit for good answers and thanks for your help. My old version does support replace so that is helping me get closer ..